# pureftpd conneting with ftp on terminal but not filezilla

Tags: ftp, centos6, pureftpd

I have a dedicated server with WHM which have installed pureftpd

the problem is:

```
$ ftp site.com
```

works alright I can use `dir` command and see my file list

however with filezilla or others like fireFTP and crossFTP, I get this:

```
Command:    MLSD
Error:  The data connection could not be established: EHOSTUNREACH - No route to host
```

I really don't understand why !? (OS: CentOS6)

- tested active and passive

Comment: I would recommend sniffing your network traffic with tcpdump to see what's actually happening there.